# I want to run an .exe command from Perl under Windows

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I've already gotten Perl to create an array of usernames (@ua); now I need to check to see if each one exists in Active Directory. The best way I thought of to do this is to run dsquery on each user and determine if the command exits with zero or nonzero. I wrote the following:

```
foreach(@ua)
{
    $out = `C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsquery.exe user -samid $_`;
}
```

When I run this, I get a repeated list of this in the command line console:

> 'C:\Windows\System32\dsquery.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

However, dsquery.exe *is* in that location, as I can prove by simply running it:

```
C:\verify_users>C:\Windows\System32\dsquery.exe user -samid ...
"CN=...,OU=...,OU=...,OU=...,DC=...,DC=...,DC=..."
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you need to run an external command, you can use the system command:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsquery.exe user -samid $_");
```

If you need a deeper control of the command, try this module: [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm)

But if you really want to do querys to Active Directory, it's better to use a specific CPAN Module, like [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aLDAP).

Comment: Expect will only work on Windows if they're using the Cygwin version, ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl will not work: http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod#___top

Answer (score 3):

As Miguel says, use Net::LDAP instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::LDAP;

my $tgt_user = shift or die "Usage: fetch_user_details <username>";

my $Server   = 'server.foo.local';
my $User     = 'user@foo.local';
my $Password = 'userpass';
my $LdapBase = 'OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=foo,DC=local';
# To AND conditions: "(&(cond1) (cond2))"
my $Filter   = "SAMAccountName=$tgt_user";


# Bind a connection
my $ad = Net::LDAP->new("ldap://$Server")
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server: $Server");
my $res = $ad->bind( $User, password=>$Password );
if ($res->code) { die("Unable to bind as user $User: ".$res->error); }

# Run the search
# Could have attrs=>'a,b,c' for a search too
$res = $ad->search(base=>$LdapBase, filter=>$Filter);
if ($res->code) { die("Failed to search: ".$res->error); }

# Display results
my $count = $res->count;
print "Found $count matches\n";

for my $entry ($res->entries) {
        $entry->dump;
        # print $entry->get_value('givenname'),"\n";
}

$ad->unbind;
exit;
```

The above should pretty much do it assuming your domain-naming is something like machine.foo.local with SBS - if not, you'll need to google around a little to see how to set up the LdapBase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with output, use the `open` function:

```
open(N, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsquery.exe user -samid $_ |");
```

or if you want to run the command only, use the `system` function:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsquery.exe user -samid $_");
```